# Cannot find element that provides DataContext in a custom control

Tags: wpf, custom-controls, datacontext

Hi I have a custom control which I use to present other xaml content.

Within the implementation of said control I have a user control that expects a view model to be bound to its data context, however the data context is always null and I am getting the following error message:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 3 : Cannot find element that provides
>   DataContext. BindingExpression:Path=OutcomeRestrictionVM;
>   DataItem=null; target element is 'XsdEnumRestrictionView' (Name='');
>   target property is 'DataContext' (type 'Object')

The Generic.xaml for my custom control is:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:ContextGroupBox}" x:Key="ContextGroupBoxTemplate">
    <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="true" >
        <Grid.Resources>
            <ControlTemplate x:Key="tplFlatButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"
                        Height="{TemplateBinding Height}"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                      VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                      TextElement.Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                      TextElement.FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}"
                      TextElement.FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"
                      TextElement.FontStretch="{TemplateBinding FontStretch}"
                      TextElement.FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}"/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
            <Style x:Key="stlFlatButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{x:Null}" />
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{x:Null}" />
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
                <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource tplFlatButton}" />
            </Style>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <Rectangle RadiusX="10" RadiusY="10" StrokeThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"  Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
        <Grid Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <!-- Group Title -->
            <Grid Grid.Row="0" Margin="5,5,5,1" >
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" RecognizesAccessKey="true" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" TextElement.Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" TextElement.FontSize="{TemplateBinding HeaderFontSize}" TextElement.FontWeight="Bold"/>
                <!--<TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="Record Access" Foreground="#4E86B8" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="14" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>-->
                <Button Command="{TemplateBinding ShowHelpCommand}" CommandParameter="{TemplateBinding ShowHelpParameter}" Style="{StaticResource stlFlatButton}" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                    <Image  Source="/Hornbill.Resources.Image;component/Shared/information.png" Width="16" Height="16" Visibility="Visible" >
                    </Image>
                </Button>
            </Grid>
            <ContentControl DataContext="{TemplateBinding DataContext}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" Grid.Row="1" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:ContextGroupBox}">
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource ContextGroupBoxTemplate}" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="7,4,7,7" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
</Style>
```

custom control ContextGroupBox.cs

```
public static double defaultHeaderFontSize = 14;

public double HeaderFontSize
{
    get { return (double)GetValue(HeaderFontSizeProperty); }
    set { SetValue(HeaderFontSizeProperty, value); }
}

// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for HeaderFontSize.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
public static readonly DependencyProperty HeaderFontSizeProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("HeaderFontSize", typeof(double), typeof(ContextGroupBox), new PropertyMetadata(defaultHeaderFontSize));

public object Header
{
    get { return (object)GetValue(HeaderProperty); }
    set { SetValue(HeaderProperty, value); }
}

// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Header.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
public static readonly DependencyProperty HeaderProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Header", typeof(object), typeof(ContextGroupBox));



public FrameworkElement Content
{
    get { return (FrameworkElement)GetValue(ContentProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ContentProperty, value); }
}

// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Content.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
public static readonly DependencyProperty ContentProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Content", typeof(FrameworkElement), typeof(ContextGroupBox));



public ICommand ShowHelpCommand
{
    get { return (ICommand)GetValue(ShowHelpCommandProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ShowHelpCommandProperty, value); }
}

// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ShowHelpCommand.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
public static readonly DependencyProperty ShowHelpCommandProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("ShowHelpCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(ContextGroupBox));

public object ShowHelpParameter
{
    get { return (object)GetValue(ShowHelpParameterProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ShowHelpParameterProperty, value); }
}

// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ShowHelpParameter.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
public static readonly DependencyProperty ShowHelpParameterProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("ShowHelpParameter", typeof(object), typeof(ContextGroupBox));


static ContextGroupBox()
{
    DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(ContextGroupBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(ContextGroupBox)));
}
```

and my implementation is:

```
<hctrl:ContextGroupBox Grid.Column="1" DataContextChanged="gbOutcomeParam_DataContextChanged_1"  Header="{l:Translate Outcome}" Name="gbOutcomeParam" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5 5">
                        <ctrl:XsdEnumRestrictionView DataContext="{Binding OutcomeRestrictionVM, Mode=OneWay}" DataContextChanged="XsdEnumRestrictionView_DataContextChanged" />
                    </hctrl:ContextGroupBox>
```

The crazy thing is that if I create a dependency property in my user control (ctrl:XsdEnumRestrictionView) and bind to that everything works fine but not when I bind to DataContext explicitly.

Ok, maybe the user control should use a property anyway but I am frustrated by the loss of DataContext and would like to understand why my custom control does not seem to have one.

Any help will be much appreciated

Thanks

Kieran

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so for an explicit bind to DataContext to work I had to set the base class of my Custom Control to HeaderedContentControl and remove the Header and Content properties.
Now it all seems to work fine, though I still do not quite understand why it didn't work when the base class was Control.